# A tiny threads pool in C

Tags: beginner, c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I'm a newbie in C, and currently following Stanford CS107 - Programming Paradigms. For assignment 6, I find it'd be better to isolate the threads management from the service logic.

The following code is a producer-consumer pattern using semaphore to limit the maximum number of threads. `recycle_threads()` itself is a thread, which automatically waits for previous threads to exit and free the resources. Users can call `create_thread()` function whenever they want to run a function in a new thread.

Feel free to leave any comment, about the coding style, design, or utility. Especially, I want to  know for what purpose, a real-life thread pool is designed, and what's the feature it must realize.

`threads_pool.h`

```c
#ifndef _THREADS_POOL_
#define _THREADS_POOL_

#define THREAD_POOL_INIT_OK 0
#define THREAD_POOL_INIT_ERR 1

typedef void *(*thread_fn)(void *arg);

/**
 * Create a new thread pool
 */
int threads_pool_init(unsigned size);

/**
 * Apply a new thread in threads pool.
 */
void create_thread(thread_fn thd_fn, void *arg);

/**
 * Notice no more threads to be created.
 * Threads pool can start to recycle and destroy resources.
 */
void threads_pool_close(void);

#endif // _THREADS_POOL_
```

`threads_pool.c`

```c
#include "threads_pool.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* threads pool */
static pthread_t *pool;
static unsigned pool_size;
static unsigned create_p;
static unsigned recycle_p;
/* semaphore */
static sem_t *create_sem;
static sem_t *recycle_sem;
static const char *kThreadPoolCreateSem = "/create_sem";
static const char *kThreadPoolRecycleSem = "/recycle_sem";
/* recycle thread id */
static pthread_t recycle_tid;
/* signal recycle thread to exit */
static volatile sig_atomic_t recycle_sig;
#define RECYCLE_RUN 0
#define RECYCLE_TO_EXIT 1

/**
 * Producer of producer-consumer pattern.
 */
void create_thread(thread_fn thd_fn, void *arg) {
    sem_wait(create_sem);
    pthread_create(pool + create_p++ % pool_size, NULL, thd_fn, arg);
    sem_post(recycle_sem);
}

/**
 * Consumer of producer-consumer pattern.
 * Automatically recycle exited threads.
 */
static void *recycle_threads(void *arg) {
    while (RECYCLE_RUN == recycle_sig) {
        sem_wait(recycle_sem);
        pthread_join(*(pool + recycle_p++ % pool_size), NULL);
        sem_post(create_sem);
    }
    while (recycle_p < create_p) {
        sem_wait(recycle_sem);
        pthread_join(*(pool + recycle_p++ % pool_size), NULL);
        sem_post(create_sem);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/**
 * Create the threads pool, and run recycle_thread() thread.
 */
int threads_pool_init(unsigned size) {
    pool = malloc(size * sizeof *pool);
    pool_size = size;
    create_p = 0;
    recycle_p = 0;
    create_sem = sem_open(kThreadPoolCreateSem, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, size);
    recycle_sem = sem_open(kThreadPoolRecycleSem, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    recycle_sig = RECYCLE_RUN;
    int code = pthread_create(&recycle_tid, NULL, recycle_threads, NULL);
    if (0 == code) return THREAD_POOL_INIT_OK;
    return THREAD_POOL_INIT_ERR;
}

/**
 * Dispose resources
 */
static void threads_pool_destroy(void) {
    free(pool); 
    sem_unlink(kThreadPoolCreateSem);
    sem_unlink(kThreadPoolRecycleSem);
}

/**
 * Signal recycle_threads() to exit, and wait it to finish it's job.
 */
void threads_pool_close(void) {
    recycle_sig = RECYCLE_TO_EXIT;
    pthread_join(recycle_tid,NULL);
    threads_pool_destroy();
}
```

A simple use-case, simulating tickets selling: `agents_tickets.c`

```c
/**
 * Using semaphore to limit maximum thread number.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404929/always-unlink-the-posix-named-semaphore-in-shared-memory?noredirect=1
 */
#include "threads_pool.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned agent_id;              // simulate an agent
    unsigned tickets_tosell;        // agent's personal goal of the day
    unsigned *tickets_pool;         // shared tickets pool
    pthread_mutex_t *pool_lock;     // mutex lock for visiting the shared tickets pool
} agent;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
static void new_agent(agent *a, unsigned agentid, unsigned tickets_num, unsigned *pool, pthread_mutex_t *lock) {
    a->agent_id = agentid;
    a->tickets_tosell = tickets_num;
    a->tickets_pool = pool;
    a->pool_lock = lock;
}

/**
 * Implement void *(*start_rtn)(void *);
 * -------------------------------------
 * Each thread execute this function.
 */
static void *sell_tickets(void *agent_addr) {
    agent *a = (agent *)agent_addr;
    while (a->tickets_tosell > 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(a->pool_lock);   // begin of race condition
        (*a->tickets_pool)--;
        fprintf(stdout, "agent@%d sells a ticket, %d tickets left in pool.\n", a->agent_id, *a->tickets_pool);
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(a->pool_lock); // end of race condition
        a->tickets_tosell--;
        fprintf(stdout, "agent@%d has %d tickets to sell.\n", a->agent_id, a->tickets_tosell);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)&a->agent_id); 
}

typedef struct {
    unsigned num_agents;
    unsigned num_tickets;
} project;

void run(project *p) {
    unsigned tickets_pool;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    agent agents[p->num_agents];
    unsigned id;

    tickets_pool = p->num_tickets;      // shared resource
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    threads_pool_init(10);  

    for (int i = 0; i < p->num_agents; i++) {
        id = i + 1;
        new_agent(&agents[i], id, p->num_tickets / p->num_agents, &tickets_pool, &lock);
        create_thread(sell_tickets, &agents[i]);
    }
    threads_pool_close();   
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
}

int main(void) {
    project p;
    p.num_agents = 30;
    p.num_tickets = 300;
    run(&p);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Keep threads alive

What you implemented is not really a thread pool, but just an elaborate way of limiting how many concurrent threads there can be. You still spawn a separate thread for each task and destroy it afterwards. But it is exactly this overhead of creating and destroying threads that you typically want to reduce by using a thread pool.

The normal solution is to keep threads in the pool alive indefinitely, and have an atomic queue of work that threads can pick work from. This can be implemented using mutexes and condition variables, see for example [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954489/how-to-utilize-a-thread-pool-with-pthreads).